# Linq agrega una columna inexistente a la query SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

Estoy teniendo un problema con LINQ, usando EntityFramework 6

Primero, para entrar en contexto, dejo el Modelo del Problema..

```
[Table("Datos_Garantizados")]
public partial class Datos_Garantizados
{
[Key]
public long Version { get; set; }

public decimal? Perdidas_Vacio { get; set; }

public decimal? Corriente_Vacio { get; set; }

public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

public decimal? Bil_Primario { get; set; }

public decimal? Bil_Secundario { get; set; }

public decimal? Bil_Terciario { get; set; }

public decimal? Aplicada_Primaria { get; set; }

public decimal? Aplicada_Secundaria { get; set; }

public decimal? Aplicada_Terciaria { get; set; }

public decimal? SobreTemp_Aceite_Max { get; set; }

public decimal? SobreTemp_Arroll_Medio { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Secundario { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Terciario { get; set; }

public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Secundario_Terciario { get; set; }

public decimal? Potencia_Ref { get; set; }

}
```

El contexto:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Vacio)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Corriente_Vacio)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_S)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_S_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_P_S)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_P_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_S_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_S)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_S_T)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Bil_Primario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Bil_Secundario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Bil_Terciario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Primaria)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Secundaria)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Terciaria)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.SobreTemp_Aceite_Max)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.SobreTemp_Arroll_Medio)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Secundario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Terciario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Secundario_Terciario)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);

modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
    .Property(e => e.Potencia_Ref)
    .HasPrecision(18, 0);
}
```

El asunto es el siguiente, cuando intento obtener la lista de Datos Garantizados con LINQ de la siguiente manera

```
var a = db.Datos_Garantizados.ToList();
```

Salta una excepción de tipo SqlException

> El nombre de columna 'Transformador_Codigo_delfos' no es válido.

Cuando depuro, viendo la Query SQL generada por linq, puede apreciarse que agrega la columna "Transformador_Codigo_delfos" que no existe en la tabla.

**Aclaración**
Hay un modelo, que tiene relación con el de Datos_Garantizados, no se si puede ser relevante este echo

```
[Table("Transformador")]
public partial class Transformador
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
    "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Transformador()
    {
        Datos_Garantizados = new HashSet<Datos_Garantizados>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }
    //varios campos más
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Datos_Garantizados> Datos_Garantizados { get; set; }
```

Es mi primer proyecto con EF y esto me está complicando la existencia :P

Desde ya muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día:

En efecto, la navegación que tienes desde Transformador a la colección de Datos_Garantizados provoca ese mapeo temporal autogenerado. Esto porque tienes una cardinalidad de que un Transformador tiene muchos Datos_Garantizados, debes marcar la navegación de vuelta, es decir un objeto Datos_Garantizados pertenece a un Transformador.

Intenta meter en tu clase Datos_Garantizados la navegación de vuelta.

```
public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Codigo_delfos")]
public virtual Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
```

Asumiendo que estás utilizando entity te recomiendo actualizar la migración de tu modelo desde la consola NuGet con el siguiente comando:

```
update-database
```

Saludos.

**Actualización:**

Si es muchos a uno puedes evitar la tabla intermedia y EF generará la colección por ti. Si tu cardinalidad es muchos a muchos y deseas conservar una tabla intermedia, entonces en el Model Builder deberías declararlo así:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransformadoresDatos>()
                .HasMany(r => r.Transformadores)
                .WithMany(p => p.Datos_Garantizados)
                .Map(rp =>
                {
                    rp.MapLeftKey("Codigo_delfos");
                    rp.MapRightKey("Versión");
                    rp.ToTable("TransformadoresDatos");
                });
```

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y sigue pidiendome por el campo que mencionaba antes, creo que puede deberse a una ForeignKey que no se como declarar en el Modelo, en la Tabla **Transformador** tengo como clave primaria *Codigo_delfos*, dentro de **Datos_Garantizados** tengo como clave primaria *Versión*, y a estos los relaciono con una tercera tabla que tiene 2 campos, *Versión* (Clave primaria) y Código_delfos, sabes como debería mapearlos en el modelo? Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola, acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, se me pasó poner la navegación de la FK. Espero sea útil. Si haces la navegación como te sugiero, que es uno a muchos desde Transformador y uno a uno desde Datos_Garantizados, te puedes ahorrar la tabla intermedia.

Comment: Intenté hacerlo, pero sigo con el mismo error, ya que dentro de la tabla **Datos_Garantizados** la columna Código_delfos no existe, esa relación existe en una tabla aparte, se te ocurre alguna idea en dicho caso? Muchísimas gracias de nuevo !

Comment: Bien, te compartí la manera de mapear la tabla intermedia que soporta relaciones muchos a muchos, forzando a utilizar el nombre de la entidad en vez de llamar a la asociación natural, que EF toma como Transformador_Codigo_Delfos. Eso me pasaba mucho al principio hasta que descubrí cómo forzar el sobrenombre de la tabla intermedia.

Comment: En mi caso es uno a muchos (Un Transformador, puede tener X Datos_Garantizados), eso se diseño de esa manera extraña en su momento, porque un Transformador sino tenía casi 200 datos, conoces algún método para mapearlo con tabla intermedia y 1 a muchos?, de nuevo gracias, la verdad te estas recontra pasando!

Comment: Listo, ya te dejé ambas maneras en el código de mi respuesta; si quieres la de uno a muchos bastará con agregar en Datos_Garantizados el mismo campo que tiene tu llave primaria en la otra tabla `public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }`, pero  además `[ForeignKey("Codigo_delfos")]
public virtual Transformador Transformador { get; set; }`, en el ejemplo que dejé de Model Builder ya renombré las llaves para que vayan de acuerdo a tu modelo, esto debería crearte una tabla llamada TransformadorDatos. Que es muchos a muchos, pero sólo inclínate por una u otra navegación, si no pasan esas cosas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por toda  la ayuda! La solución fue reestructurar la base de datos nomas, eliminé la tabla intermedia y agregué el Código_delfos dentro de la tabla Datos_Garantizados

Comment: Enhorabuena. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que tiene relevancia esa relación, si le dices a Transformador que tiene una colección de Datos_Garantizados entonces EF asume que Datos_Garantizados debe tener un TransformadorId (En este caso Codigo_delfos que fue lo que establecistes como Key) para poder hacer el 1 a muchos. Te recomiendo agregar a Datos_Garantizados:

```
public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }
public Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
```

de esta forma EF reconoce la relación con Transformador

luego de migrar debería funcionarte. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Primero que nada muchas gracias. Lo intenté, pero no fue la solución, estoy seguro que el problema está por el lado de la declaración de la llave foránea. En mi base de datos, existe una tabla intermedia, que tiene como clave primaria Versión (que es la clave de Datos_Garantizados) y Código_delfos (que es la clave primaria de Transformador), lo que no encuentro, es con que etiqueta puedo asignarle ese campo al objeto transformador, vos sabrías? Reitero, Muchas gracias!